# Tracking other accounts on Twitter

Tags: twitter, analytics, twitter-integration, tweetdeck

I'd like to track multiple accounts and keywords on Twitter and receive all @ posts regarding the accounts in one feed and all # posts regarding the keywords in another.  Then I'd like to be able to monitor if I engage with users that mentioned these accounts or keywords by tagging certain Tweets and monitoring if I replied to them.

From there, ideally, I'd be able to analyze the results of my Tweets to them to see how effective they are across the different keywords, accounts, etc. and whether or not people click the links I post.

I've been using TweetDeck but I can't find out how to put all the account feeds or hashtags in one column, nor does it provide any analytics.

How can I better use TweetDeck to accomplish this?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, so I have removed that aspect from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try HootSuite.com or bufferapp.com

These are pioneers for your sophisticated Social Media Management.

One of my friend is working on a similar concept, will share when it's ready. Till then try the above apps out. :-)